# Pseudocylindrical projection into (X, Y) pixels

Tags: java, gis

Despite being able to convert LAT / LON coordinates into pixels for a Mercator projection, I could not figure out how to do the same for this pseudocylindrical projection described in this Patterson map available in http://www.shadedrelief.com/political, that is 13661 x 7853 pixels.

I have a city, like 'Rio de Janeiro' (-22,9068, -43,1729) and I want to output the pixels (x, y) where the city is located.

I have digged into some reference, without success. I cannot post the links here because of my reputation, but they are all inside the link given above (search for Patterson projection).

My Mercator Java code / Excel code is something like:

```
    pixelX = (Longitude+180) / (width/360)
    pixelY = height/2 - (width * mercN / (2*PI()))

    where mercN = LOG(Tan((PI()/4 + Latitude*PI())/360)
```

And it naturally does not work for a pseudocylindrical projection.

Comment: This link could help: http://cartographicperspectives.org/index.php/journal/article/view/cp78-patterson-et-al/1362 and also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_Earth_projection

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of that projection before ... There was an [article published about it](http://cartographicperspectives.org/index.php/journal/article/view/cp78-patterson-et-al/1362) explaining the background.

This is where they also describe a formular how to transform lon / lats in their new projection:

```
x = λ
y = c1 · φ + c2 · φ**5 + c3 · φ**7 + c4 · φ**9
```